# enable and desable all elements in one component/HTML

Tags: html, angular, components

I am a beginner developer, I am trying to validate some users permissions access, for that I construct a service that validate user role permissions agains the views that they have enable returning true or false. For now I have messages "Welcome" and "you dont have access" to test it; now that I need to do is enable all the page/component then some functions (forms, buttos, tables views etc) or disable all the component in case that the user doesn't have permission to access. I need that user can see the page but only if he has the permission will be able to use it. Anyone have any idea how i can do it?

> 

```
 export class WriteComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public userMngmtService: UserMngmtRolesService, public router: Router, public routeComponent : ActivatedRoute,public toaster: ToastrService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(){
    // this.route = this.router.url;
    // console.log('lelelel',this.route)
    var route = "write";
    var role = localStorage.getItem('roleId');
    this.userMngmtService.validatepermissions(role,route).subscribe(
      (canAccess: any) => {
        console.log('canAccess', canAccess);
        if(canAccess == true){

          this.toaster.success("Welcome!")
        }else{
          if(canAccess == false){
            this.toaster.error("U don't have permissions to access!")
          }
        }
      });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a boolean property in your class e.g. `canAccess` and then assign true or false to this property inside your if/else statement:

```
 export class WriteComponent implements OnInit {

   canAccess: boolean;

   constructor(public userMngmtService: UserMngmtRolesService, public router: Router, public routeComponent : ActivatedRoute,public toaster: ToastrService) {

   }

   ngOnInit(){
     var route = "write";
     var role = localStorage.getItem('roleId');
     this.userMngmtService.validatepermissions(role,route).subscribe(
       (canAccess: any) => {
         console.log('canAccess', canAccess);
         if(canAccess == true){
           this.canAccess = true; 
         }else{
           if(canAccess == false){
             this.canAccess = false;
           }
         }
       });
   }
}
```

You can then use this property inside your html with `*ngIf` to show/not show specific elements:

```
<div *ngIf="canAccess; else noAccess">
  Welcome
  <!-- put your forms, buttons, tables etc. in here -->
</div>

<ng-template #noAccess>
 <div>You do not have permission to view this</div>
</ng-template>
```